# Display image in web server <img>

Tags: html, image, file

I have multiple images in the following folder: /var/www/xxx/web/images/orders/712. The file name is: 1332_CARA_24_225_31654_thumb.jpg

I want to show it with an  html label. I doing this:

```
<img src="1332_CARA_24_225_31654_thumb.jpg">
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: There isn't an obvious problem (although your `alt` attribute is missing). What does your server's error log say? What does the Net tab of your browser's developer tools say?

Comment: I don't get it, what is the question? Doesn't the image display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `.../web` is pointing to your root so try following:

```
<img src="images/orders/712/1332_CARA_24_225_31654_thumb.jpg" />
```

Comment: @Yurly Galanter, I was just about to submit my answer stating the exact same thing.

Comment: @nandophillips, if it worked for you, please accept the answer,note that: you can define `base` tag for your resource available by name and don't need absolute address.

Answer (score 0):

The path described in the IMG tag's SRC attribute is a relative path (unless you begin the path with a "/").

So if your `HTML` file is located in the same folder as the image, it should work. 
If, for example, your HTML file is located in the `web` folder, then your `SRC` attribute would need to be :

```
images/orders/712/1332_CARA_24_225_31654_thumb.jpg
```